# i want to split my java string array when multiple charactors in nearly in my string

Tags: java, arrays, split

i've used .split function for do the task but as i noticed when there are two special charactors in near my array filled with a space here is my code

```
String strLine="cat dog man()home(String[welcome)throws , guess {";
String[] words = strLine.split("\\{+|\\(+|\\[+|\\]+|\\)+|\\,|\\s+");
int len=words.length;

for(int x=0;x<len;x++){
      System.out.println(words[x]);
}
```

result showing as[image]

i want my array without spaces
any suggestions

Comment: hint: character list and "one or more" quantifier

Comment: Why not just use an if statement? `if (!words[x].trim().isEmpty()) { System.out.println(words[x]); }`

Comment: @Raghav, *I want my array without spaces* - not display the array without spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want adjacent separator characters to be treated as a single separator, just combine them in a single character class.

```regex
\{+|\(+|\[+|\]+|\)+|\,|\s+     →     [{(\[\]),\s]+
```

However, since you don't have a `+` on the `,`, it seems that multiple commas should not be treated as a single separator, so we need to handle that differently.

It also seems like you forgot the `}`.

```regex
[{}()\[\]\s]*,[{}()\[\]\s]*|[{}()\[\]\s]+
```

As Java literal:

```java
"[{}()\\[\\]\\s]*,[{}()\\[\\]\\s]*|[{}()\\[\\]\\s]+"
```